# Find shortest and longest path with recursive postgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I am new to PostgreSQL and in recursive queries and have this following problem:
I have the following tables

- node(id, colour)
- edge(n1,n2)

I have to write a query with a recursive statement that returns the shortest and longest paths between each pair of nodes. The output should look like this: *(id1,id2, shortpath,longpath)*

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Note that in a generic graph, there is no "longest" path because you can just keep looping around.  Also, SQL is not the best tool for this, so it won't be the most efficient way to accomplish this.

Comment: The graph is not endless. The nodes go one way for example (A goes to B) and not backwards(B to A). 
Sample data: 
(A,B)
(A,C)
(B,D)
(D,C)
(C,E)

And the results should look like : (A,E,2,4) etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL is probably not the best tool to do this, but you can do it using a recursive CTE.

For example:

```
with recursive
p as (
  select n1, n2 as n, '/' || n1 || '/' as path, 1 as cost from edge where n1 = 'A'
 union all
  select p.n1, e.n2, p.path || e.n2 || '/', cost + 1
  from p
  join edge e on e.n1 = p.n
  where p.path not like '/' || e.n1 || '/'
    and p.n <> 'E'
)
select 'A' as source, 'E' as target, 
  (select min(cost) from p where n = 'E'),
  (select max(cost) from p where n = 'E');
```

Result:

```
source  target  min  max 
------- ------- ---- --- 
A       E       2    4
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kcaBg4c3VvfXfzjLwCRhUb/0).